# array_sum() expects parameter 1 to be array, double given

Tags: php, arrays, matrix

i have these values in an multidimensional array:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => float 0.11521247274056
      1 => float 0.081839214900844
      2 => float 0.084168850912272
      3 => float 0.18520831868443
  1 => 
    array
      0 => float 0.92169978192452
      1 => float 0.65471371920675
      2 => float 0.84168850912272
      3 => float 0.43215274359699
  2 => 
    array
      0 => float 0.23042494548113
      1 => float 0.13094274384135
      2 => float 0.16833770182454
      3 => float 0.18520831868443
  3 => 
    array
      0 => float 0.038404157580188
      1 => float 0.09353053131525
      2 => float 0.056112567274848
      3 => float 0.061736106228142
```

Now, what i want is the sum for each group. Something like:

[0][0] + [0][1] + [0][2] + [0][3]

With this code, i got this error: array_sum() expects parameter 1 to be array, double given

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $numCol; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < $numCol; $j++) {
        $sumResult[] = array_sum($result[$i][$j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The error says what you need to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass in an array into `array_sum` but you are passing each value in explicitly. Try this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $numCol; $i++) {
    $sumResult[] = array_sum($result[$i]);        
}
```